# CARTO - Carto builder SQL query for map Extent and dynamic calculation

Tags: sql, builder, bounding-box, cartodb

I have a builder enterprise account at carto.com

I have an SQL query for an empty layer defined as follow :

```
SELECT (sum(montant_periode_en_cours) OVER() - sum(montant_periode_precedente)OVER()) / 
        sum(montant_periode_precedente) OVER() as tx_croissance_moy , *
from "anagraph-clement".purvodka_master_attempt_2
```

It works well as it returns my all the points I need on the map with the calculation in the right field.

BUT !

The formula widget is not able to display a dynamic number based on the current map extent data.

Do you know any way to achieve that BBOX dynamic calculation on the fly ?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal because the query is wrapped to retrieve the metric based on the bounding box, but your aggregation is computed **before** that wrapping.

I'm afraid there's no way to achieve that using BUILDER, and I can only think on doing that manually on a custom application. In that scenario, you can use Leaflet/GMaps methods to get the current bounding box, and then using SQL API get the KPI you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for the explaination !

Comment: @CGlog please if this solves your doubts (even maybe not your problem), please mind to mark it as resolved, we (CARTO) track the label here and try to have the number of unresolved  as low as possible :_)